WooCommerce single-product.twig showing product info twice
When using the recommended single-product.twig from Timber's docs it results in the product information showing up twice.
The second render of the product information (below the related products section) comes from:
{% include ["partials/tease-product.twig"] with { products: related_products } %}
Screenshot of WooCommerce product detail page
Should this line be removed from the documentation?
Removing {% include ["partials/tease-product.twig"] with { products: related_products } %} stops the product information showing a second time.

"Should this line be removed from the documentation?" I don't think so. The product info appearing twice could be coming from another template file. Are you including partials/tease-product.twig anywhere else in your theme? When asking a question be sure to include a [mcve] so the problem can be replicated by other users.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
